# How to implement sql replication when subsciber cannot acces the publisher

Tags: replication

I have 2 servers

Server A (Publisher) and Server B (Subscriber)

However server A can access Server B but Server B cannot access Server A.

There are no VPN between these servers Server A can access B over the internet but B cannot do the same

[image: Architecture]